# :selected state on looped react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am basically wanting to do individual selected states on divs that I am rendering in a loop. I can only see a way to change the color of all of the rendered divs, but rather I wish to change the color of which ever one was clicked. Below is the code for the loop.

```
  renderSports() {
    const {sports} = this.props
    return sports.valueSeq().map(sport => this.renderActualSports(sport))
  },

  renderActualSports(sport) {
    const {sportCount} = this.props
    return (
      <div className="sportSeparator">
        {sport} {this.renderCount(sportCount.get(sport))}
      </div>
    )
  },
```

This will basically just render a list of some sports. I want to change the color of a selected sport on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the items that were clicked in your component state.

Assuming you would store this highlighted items in `this.state.highlighted` and that your sport variable is a string or number:

```
renderActualSports(sport) {
    const {sportCount} = this.props
    return (
      <div
        className="sportSeparator"
        onClick={this.highlight(sport)}
        style={{color: this.state.highlighted.indexOf(sport) > -1 && 'red' : ''}}
      >
        {sport} {this.renderCount(sportCount.get(sport))}
      </div>
    )
  },

  highlight(sport) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({highlighted: [...this.state.highlighted, sport]});
    }
  }
```

So what you are doing is onClick on the div you add that sport to the `this.state.highlighted` array and when displaying the list. you check if that sport is in the array and if yes you change the color using an inline style

Comment: what is the initial state for this?

Comment: also when one sport is clicked, I want to toggle the other off @klugjo?

Comment: the initial state is []. you mean only one sport can be selected at a time ?

Comment: If only one sport can be selected at a time, it is even simpler, you just store a single string in your state and you set that to the current item clicked each time